# Stopping CAKeyframeAnimation in middle

Tags: iphone, ios

Currently i am moving a png image using CAKeyframeAnimation along a path for 30 seconds. Is there any way to stop this moving image in between 0-30 seconds on tapping a button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will remove the animation...

```
[yourView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: Any idea, what to do if the receiver is an NSWindow? NSWindows don't provide removeAllAnimations; unfortunately.

Comment: NSWindow is from the OSX SDK, not the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Well... do you want to stop the animation or would you simply like to pause/resume? If you'd like to pause, then there is something like this:

```
func pause(){
    pausedTime = foo.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    foo.layer.speed = 0
    foo.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime!
}
func play(){
    pausedTime = foo.layer.timeOffset
    foo.layer.speed = 1.0
    foo.layer.timeOffset = 0
    let timeSincePause = foo.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil) - pausedTime!
    foo.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

Comment: This only works for the first time the animation gets "play->pause->play". Any subsequent "play" will not start from the paused position.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
[view.layer removeAnimationForKey:kFrameAnimationKey];
```